# How to update a value in an array property in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter program, I use Firestore to store a document named DocumentA, which contains an array property called List. During the program's execution, I retrieve this document from Firestore. At some point, I may modify one of the Products in the list and want to synchronize the changes back to Firestore. Initially, I thought of querying the specific location of the MusicItem based on its properties, and then updating the target object. However, I don't think this approach is ideal because it requires querying the entire list every time an update is needed. Is there a better way to handle this?

```
  Future<List<MusicItem>> GetAllMusicItems() async {
    List<MusicItem> ret = [];
    ret = (userDocSnapShot!['MusicItems'] as List<dynamic>)
        .map((e) => MusicItem.fromMap(e))
        .toList();
    return ret;
  }

  Future<void> UpdateMusicItem(MusicItem newItem) async {

    DocumentReference docRef = userDocSnapShot!.reference;

    await GetAllMusicItems().then((musicItems) {
  
      if (!musicItems.isEmpty) {
        Logger().d(
            " === UpdateMusicItem  productList length  ${musicItems.length} ====  newItem Name ${newItem.name} ");
        MusicItem? oldItem =
            musicItems.firstWhere((product) => product.name == newItem.name);

        if (oldItem != null) {
          Logger().d(" === updatedProduct  ${oldItem!.name} ==== ");

          docRef.update({
            'MusicItems': FieldValue.arrayRemove([oldItem!.toMap()])
          });
          docRef.update({
            'MusicItems': FieldValue.arrayUnion([newItem.toMap()])
          });
        }
      } else {
        Logger().d(" === UpdateMusicItem   ==== ");
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Besides Frank's answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) will also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to update an existing item in an array field. You can atomically add an item to a list, or remove an item from the list, but to update an item you will need to:

1. Read the existing array from the database
2. Update the array in memory in your application code
3. Write the entire array field back to the database